# Wrap function and preserve input and return types?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to wrap a function like this and preserve types?

```
const example = (alpha: string): string => alpha + 'beta';
const wrappedFn = (fn: Function) => fn;
```

How can I pull the types out of `fn` and return the same input and return as the passed in function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can preserve all input argument types (even if there are more args) using tuples in rest parameters:

```
const example = (alpha: string): string => alpha + 'beta';
const wrappedFn = <A extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: A) => R) => (...args: A): R => {
    console.log("executing");
    return fn(...args);   
};

wrappedFn(example)("a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics to make `fn` return a function that returns the same type as the input function:

```
const wrappedFn = <T>(fn: (T) => T) => fn;
```

Comment: Hey thanks, This doesn't reflect input types accurately, showing as `any`.